# overlap two div elements

Tags: html, css

I've got a basic `html` that contain such lines

```
<div id="circle">
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
<div id="audio-player-core" class="controls">
    <img src="" alt="nothing" width="65px" height="65px">
</div>
```

And `css`

```
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#slider {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.controls {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#audio-player-core {
     border: 1px solid;
     border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
     border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

But I cannot make them overlap each other (specifically I want for rectangle to start at the center of the circle while hiding part of circle inside). When I try to move one via `margin` - another moves and so on.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63jbuo18/3/)

How to overlap them?

Comment: Use position relative or absolute, and z-index between us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). For example,

```
#audio-player-core { 
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 60px;
}
```

```css
#circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#slider {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.controls {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#audio-player-core {
     border: 1px solid;
     border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
     border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
     position: absolute;
     left: 50px;
     top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle">
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
<div id="audio-player-core" class="controls">
  <img src="" alt="nothing" width="65px" height="65px">
</div>
```

Comment: so I should have set `position` for `core` item. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome! :) Check the article (link given in the answer) on MDN. It will make things clearer.